# How to prove Preconditioned Richardson - Steepest Descend converges

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]
Hi, I am trying to solve this problem but I am feeling like I am missing some prerequisites. Can help me solve this ? or at least a reference with a book where this is solved ?
$\text{Let } A \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) \text{ be a symmetric and positive definite matrix, and let } b \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ define the linear system } Ax = b \text{. Let } P \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) \text{ be a symmetric and positive definite preconditioning matrix. Show that the sequence of approximations } x(k), k \geq 0, \text{ corresponding to the preconditioned Richardson method with maximal slope (PR-SD) using the update rule above converges}.$